# Getting the SUM of all members of a group at member level

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 3 objects in my PowerBI model :

- Objectives
- Sites
- Groups

They are connected as follows
Objectives → [Site_Code] → Site → [Group_Code] → Group

An objective is defined for a site. 
A site is part of a group.

For a calculation, I need at site level to get the sum of the objectives of all members of this group.

So here's where I am in DAX Studio :

```
EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SITES,
    "Obj_Site",
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(OBJECTIVES[OBJ_Value])
    ),
    "Obj_Group",
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(OBJECTIVES[OBJ_Value]),
        ALL(SITES) // ??? something something
    )
)
```

What I'm able to do is either getting the site's objective or the sum of all objectives but not the sum of the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ALL` to specify what column filters to remove or `ALLEXCEPT` to specify what filters to keep.

I would try instead of `ALL(SITES)` to use either `ALL(SITES[Site_Code])` to just remove filters on the site code or `ALLEXCEPT(SITES, SITES[Group_Code])` to keep just the group code filter.

I suspect the latter is going to work better since there may be additional columns in your table that also provide row context other than `Site_Code`, in which case you'd need to remove them as well to get the right result.